# Mongoid Geo Near Average Distance unit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, geospatial

This is how I am calculating average distance betwoon two indexed locations;

```
:distance => User.where(:email => worker).geo_near(pb.location).average_distance.round(5)
```

It is giving me a number all right but I can't find out what unit it is in? Or how can I convert it in miles. As an example it is giving me 3.97... as the distance between LA and LV.